# How could i get the keyboard height in Flutter 3.10.0?

Tags: flutter

I used to know that `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` is the code the get the keyboard height in Flutter. However, after I upgrade the Flutter’s version from 3.7.1 to 3.10.0 and Dart 3.0.0 this morning, I checked that these code doesn’t give me the height of the keyboard anymore. It's display 0 only. I research and found there is a `View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` code and try it. But the result that give me doesn’t seems the height of the keyboard. Is there a changes on getting the keyboard height in Flutter 3.10.0? Here is the result of `flutter doctor -v` in my pc.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.0, on macOS 13.3.1 22E261 darwin-arm64, locale ko-KR)
    • Flutter version 3.10.0 on channel stable at /Users/daehyeon/Documents/flutter-dev/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 84a1e904f4 (2일 전), 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
    • Engine revision d44b5a94c9
    • Dart version 3.0.0
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/daehyeon/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E222b
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.3.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app
    • Flutter plugin version 73.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 223.8888

[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • 회사 iphone (mobile) • 00008101-000909362681001E            • ios • iOS 16.4.1 20E252
    • iPhone 14 (mobile) • DC9CA49D-A287-4843-83FF-D826BC6F6F04 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ScreenUtilInit(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      designSize: const Size(376, 812),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return const Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Spacer(),
              TextField(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does it mean, to set the `useInheritedMediaQuery` to `true` in the SreenUtilInitWidget?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**